# Json data reading using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, object

how can i get the value of User[keywords][] using jquery ? i tried to get like console.log(User[keywords]); but it does not work

```
{
  "User[firstName]": "",
  "User[lastName]": "",
  "User[city]": "",
  "User[countryCode]": "",
  "User[gender]": "",
  "User[userType]": "",
  "User[zip]": "",
  "User[email]": "",
  "User[age]": "",
  "User[fullAddress]": "",
  "CustomValue[11][fieldValue]": "",
  "CustomValue[5][fieldValue]": "",
  "CustomValue[1][fieldValue]": "",
  "CustomValue[6][fieldValue]": "",
  "CustomValue[7][fieldValue]": "",
  "CustomValue[2][fieldValue]": "",
  "CustomValue[8][fieldValue]": "",
  "CustomValue[9][fieldValue]": "",
  "CustomValue[4][fieldValue]": "",
  "CustomValue[10][fieldValue]": "",
  "CustomValue[3][fieldValue]": "",
  "User[teams][]": null,
  "": "",
  "User[keywords][]": [
    "52",
    "53",
    "54"
  ],
  "User[searchType]": "1",
  "User[keywordsExclude][]": null,
  "User[id]": "",
  "yt1": ""
}
```

Comment: `data["User[keywords][]"];` isn't this working for you?

Comment: Once you've got past your immediate problem, you should consider (if it's yours) fixing the source of your JSON to be a little more sane.  If it's not yours, go complain at them :)

Comment: in which variable you stored these data?

Comment: for example if it var data then you can try data.User[keywords]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you need to use your data with `[]` square brackets to target specific keys:

```js
var data = {
  "User[firstName]": "",
  "User[lastName]": "",
  "User[city]": "",
  "User[countryCode]": "",
  "User[gender]": "",
  "User[userType]": "",
  "User[zip]": "",
  "User[email]": "",
  "User[age]": "",
  "User[fullAddress]": "",
  "CustomValue[11][fieldValue]": "",
  "CustomValue[5][fieldValue]": "",
  "CustomValue[1][fieldValue]": "",
  "CustomValue[6][fieldValue]": "",
  "CustomValue[7][fieldValue]": "",
  "CustomValue[2][fieldValue]": "",
  "CustomValue[8][fieldValue]": "",
  "CustomValue[9][fieldValue]": "",
  "CustomValue[4][fieldValue]": "",
  "CustomValue[10][fieldValue]": "",
  "CustomValue[3][fieldValue]": "",
  "User[teams][]": null,
  "": "",
  "User[keywords][]": [
    "52",
    "53",
    "54"
  ],
  "User[searchType]": "1",
  "User[keywordsExclude][]": null,
  "User[id]": "",
  "yt1": ""
};
var pre = '<pre>'+ JSON.stringify(data["User[keywords][]"], 0, 0) +'</pre>'
document.write(pre)
```

Answer (score 2):

If this json is assigned to variable **obj**:

```
console.log(obj['User[keywords][]']);
```